# How do I set a maximum field input

Tags: java, max

I have made a constructor where a user inputs a rating into a class. I however want to set the Maximum rating to 10, as the specification asks that the Highest rating that can be set is 10.

Here is the constructor:

```
      public Card(String nam, int rat, int cred)
      {
        name = nam;
         rating = rat;
          credits = cred;
      }
```

So when I create a new Card, if a user inputs a number greater than 10 it should warn them that 10 is the highest number they can set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, validate all input prior to continue with the code logic, like so:

```
public Card(String nam, int rat, int cred) {
    if (rat > 10) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Maximum rating allowed is 10. You've entered " + rat);
    }

    //Other logic here, like
    rating = rat;
}
```

I used an [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html?is-external=true) for this very purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Throw an exception in the constructor if `rat` is not within the bounds that are required.

```
public Card(String nam, int rat, int cred)
{
    if (rat < 0 || rat > 10)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Rating has to be within valid bounds of 0 through 10");
    }
    name = nam;
    rating = rat;
    credits = cred;
}
```

Comment: The Java SDK doesn't contain the exception `InvalidArgumentException`. It has [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html?is-external=true) though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can have any code logic you want in a constructor.  So just add it to the constructor.

Example:

```
  public Card(String nam, int rat, int cred)
  {
    name = nam;
    if (rating <= 10)
          rating = rat;
    else
          rating = 10;
      credits = cred;
  }
```

If you want to reprompt, you can throw an exception, or reprompt in the constructor itself (harder to make sure you have proper inputs).  As long as you handle the exception properly, its probably the best option if you want a reprompt.